# WebGrid and EF4 attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Is there any way use DataAnnotations attributes with MVC3 WebGrid extension?

I using some EF4 DataAnnotations attributes like [ScaffoldColumn(true)] and [Display(Description = "Name", Prompt = "Enter name", ShortName = "Name")]. But it is not have any effect with WebGrid.

So how I can use my DataAnnotations attributes with WebGrid if it is possible?

---

UPDATE   OK, Darin Dimitrov is compitly answered to my question. And of couse it's +1.
But for work the [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) is much better then WebGrid. It's my choiсe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebGrid helper doesn't use DataAnnotations. You could customize the columns and use Editor/Display templates inside them if you want those attributes to have some effect. You could also have something among the lines:

```
@{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: ViewData
                 .ModelMetadata
                 .Properties
                 .Single()
                 .Properties
                 .Select(
                     p => grid.Column(
                         columnName: p.PropertyName,
                         header: p.ShortDisplayName
                     )
                 )
)
```

Comment: Is there any helpers who do use DataAnnotations?

Comment: @FFire, yes Editor/Display templates: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)`